# whats wrong with this mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="SELECT product.title, product.description, product.price, product.product_id,  
FROM product
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_category WHERE category_id='$categoryid') AS a
ON a.product_id=product.product_id";      

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and the i get this warning:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in......
```

Comment: Why are you using an INNER JOIN as well as a subquery? Why not just `SELECT product.title, product.description, product.price, product.product_id FROM product INNER JOIN product_category ON product_category.product_id = product.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = '$categoryid'`

Comment: You have a full stop at the end of line 1 - product.product_id.  (might be a comma, this screen is tiny :) )

Comment: @FreudianSlip is right. Remove the last comma at the end of the very first line

Comment: While you should not use `mysql_*` anymore but switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, you should learn to use the provided capabilities like `mysql_error` that would have helped you to detect that issue.

Comment: @nl-x because if i removed the sub query, then, i will get every product. and here i only need products in a given category.

Comment: @user3697664 No it wont. Just copy paste my query, it should give you the same results as your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma even after the last selected field.

Comment: oh..how come i didnt notice that. thanks alot..

Answer (score 0):

Might be ambigous, try to change it to:
...
FROM product p INNER JOIN 
...
and replace the product. prefix in the first part of your SELECT statement by p.

If this still does not work, copy the complete command to phpmyadmin and execute it there (replace $categoryid with a real value first), you usually get a clue as to what is wrong with your statement.

Also there are commands to return more information on mysql errors in php as well (mysql_error)